# Looping through ggplot to create multiple graphs

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

I would like to loop to ggplot2 to create multiple plots. I either want to save the plots individuals as png files or put them in a file of some sort.

Here is my data:

```
graphs<-structure(list(unqid = c(248, 248, 248, 260, 260, 260), Time = c("0", 
"2 Years", "6 years", "0", "2 Years", "6 years"), GlcCer..d18.1.24.0. = c(392.053548533786, 
173.290788496984, 3705.77443834855, 465.331103793138, 967.749312174098, 
747.630597259739), GlcCer..d18.1.22.0. = c(482.088375817056, 
254.854448566389, 4988.80485026693, 571.063743322225, 939.391472143236, 
768.77991521974), SM.d18.1.20.0. = c(28672.2895018695, 13196.8589515893, 
56167.0664748886, 27332.707983709, 24921.9953042692, 36520.1408526379
), SM.d18.1.24.0. = c(26083.782634532, 11475.1218476637, 88585.8234565341, 
19668.2512106659, 22312.971305909, 23989.9271962257), Cer.d18.0.24.0. = c(203.041537286274, 
87.8984583301296, 345.026948321681, 113.63798428895, 91.6431430559489, 
79.6682688542247), GlcCer..d18.1.16.0. = c(119.586951218119, 
84.2784695405782, 430.631169371862, 132.359124161101, 143.596202137092, 
164.891337507055), Cer.d18.1.17.0. = c(5.65513705275648, 10.2926963643725, 
25.7531945158303, 6.8836736534046, 14.2351524354933, 10.4387851992517
), Cer.d18.1.24.0. = c(1671.33460737205, 1461.26838249666, 3365.11466246641, 
1539.70084125062, 2449.53479116483, 1960.50305100894), SM.d18.1.16.0. = c(41211.4398529659, 
33548.0124917944, 105828.065018909, 44295.6016009965, 52582.1187541458, 
43823.0428789309), SM.d18.0.20.0. = c(1253.50334022353, 846.575047211137, 
3031.85531410421, 1399.12291673709, 1074.45154117799, 1196.4626072147
), PC.36.1. = c(29684.9312200963, 25700.9298747554, 65837.4174903136, 
98427.2699693964, 79510.6660875297, 47843.3560210278), SM.d18.1.22.0. = c(47795.7949831908, 
30990.1744028016, 127729.716872227, 47799.0946882277, 46721.7978249562, 
63520.9775652175), error_GlcCer..d18.1.24.0. = c(936.074372976329, 
907.663397420009, 817.919045409943, 936.074372976329, 907.663397420009, 
817.919045409943), error_GlcCer..d18.1.22.0. = c(1429.70389874767, 
1363.38065481112, 1020.70230576293, 1429.70389874767, 1363.38065481112, 
1020.70230576293), error_SM.d18.1.20.0. = c(29777.7387648987, 
31045.3029950327, 25052.1146877277, 29777.7387648987, 31045.3029950327, 
25052.1146877277), error_SM.d18.1.24.0. = c(54561.0927529135, 
58196.3248533819, 36632.993324447, 54561.0927529135, 58196.3248533819, 
36632.993324447), error_Cer.d18.0.24.0. = c(141.78335403169, 
136.519842007374, 117.870286266133, 141.78335403169, 136.519842007374, 
117.870286266133), error_GlcCer..d18.1.16.0. = c(81.086154560981, 
78.5631969448643, 82.7830831042636, 81.086154560981, 78.5631969448643, 
82.7830831042636), error_Cer.d18.1.17.0. = c(11.4223412739451, 
12.4595367519436, 8.37753359127409, 11.4223412739451, 12.4595367519436, 
8.37753359127409), error_Cer.d18.1.24.0. = c(1299.71767331814, 
1351.19164564217, 1172.54994122983, 1299.71767331814, 1351.19164564217, 
1172.54994122983), error_SM.d18.1.16.0. = c(24837.9873076409, 
22995.6727700877, 20459.682202334, 24837.9873076409, 22995.6727700877, 
20459.682202334), error_SM.d18.0.20.0. = c(2510.11807880196, 
2638.13669739695, 1574.50698807042, 2510.11807880196, 2638.13669739695, 
1574.50698807042), error_PC.36.1. = c(71563.8361377675, 68243.1628999811, 
57429.4826536701, 71563.8361377675, 68243.1628999811, 57429.4826536701
), error_SM.d18.1.22.0. = c(86304.1639109951, 86447.2218496344, 
64606.0303862625, 86304.1639109951, 86447.2218496344, 64606.0303862625
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Here is the object I loop through:

```
min.sig1<-c("GlcCer..d18.1.24.0.", "GlcCer..d18.1.22.0.", "SM.d18.1.20.0.", "SM.d18.1.24.0.",
           "Cer.d18.0.24.0.", "GlcCer..d18.1.16.0.", "Cer.d18.1.17.0.", "Cer.d18.1.24.0.",
           "SM.d18.1.16.0.",    "SM.d18.0.20.0.", "PC.36.1.",   "SM.d18.1.22.0.")
```

Here is the code I have so far. But it doesn't seem to produce any plot that I can see (although it also doesn't produce any errors and the code appears to run).

```
for (variable in min.sig1) {
  ggplot(graphs, aes(x = Time, y = variable)) +
    geom_line(color = "blue") +  # Line plot
    geom_ribbon(aes(
      ymin = paste0(variable, "- error_", variable), 
      ymax = paste0(variable, "+ error_", variable)), 
                fill = "blue", alpha = 0.3) +  # Shaded error bars
  labs(x = "Time Point", y = variable, 
       title = "Line graph with shaded error bars") +  # Labels
  theme_minimal()  # Optional: Apply a minimal theme
}
```

Comment: (1) `ggplotr2` plots are rendered when they are printed explicitly (`print(...)`) or implicitly (`ggplot()+...` interactively on the console), so you need to either explicitly print them each in the loop or capture them in a `list` for printing later. (2) This will also fail in a new way: ggplot renders _lazily_, which means that `variable` will be realized by ggplot only when you print afterward, at which point it will be the last value within `min.sig1`, so this should likely be done in `lapply`.

Comment: Replace `for (variable in min.sig1) {...}` with `myplots <- lapply(min.sig1, function(variable){...})`, and then the list will contain all correct plots.